# Unable to edit all rows SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm pretty sure this is a simple one but I'm struggling to get to the bottom of this. I have a table which when I went into the 'Edit all rows' option I could update. I have just done a botched update query and wiped out 3,000 zip codes. I now have to go in and manually edit some of the key zip codes we use but I now get the follwoing error messgae:

> Now row was updated
>
> The data in row 121 was not committed Error Source:
>   Microsoft.Sql.Server.Manangement.Data.Tools. Error Message: The row
>   value(s) updated or deleted either do not make the row unique or they
>   alter multiple rows (53 rows)

Problem is I'm only trying to update one cell by making the value 01830 rather than the current value of 1830 (basically it has lost the zero)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add your update query and structure of your table please

Comment: Hi MikkaRin, all columns are set to nvarchar(255), query below UPDATE [Property_GeoRes]
SET Postal_Code = 01832 WHERE EM_Zone = 'MA' AND CITY = 'Haverhill'

Comment: Any unique constraint in your table?

Comment: Sadly not this was a dump from an Excel spreadsheet. Schoolboy error which is why I'm now in the process of rebuilding the table again. To think I was one update away from completing it :-(

Comment: You can use ROW_NUMBER http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx to make them unique by selecting what you have into a new table, then use the editor to fix one at a time.

Comment: This is why you never design a table without a PK. Add a Pk to the table and the problem goes away because you can unique identify the record.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to edit these one at a time in SSMS it will fail in the  GUI editor, you need to use actual update statements run as a query.  The editor is always trying to update 1 row only, if you do not have any unique identifier for the row you cannot update only 1 from the editor as it cannot tell which of the non unique rows you want to update.

Comment: Good point about the GUI, there is no circumstance in which the GUI shoudl ever be used to change records. Users should not have access to it and any dev changes shoud be in scripts that are committed to source control.